# how to make selective connection with google drive api (android)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-drive-android-api

How to limit `google-drive-api`'s `offline connection feature` to `only wifi`?

I use this code to upload my file, and it works. but....

```
val newDriveResult = Drive.DriveApi
                          .newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                          .await()
val driveOutputStream = newDriveResult.driveContents
                                      .outputStream


driveOutputStream = /* make driveOutputStream contain my data stream to upload */
val metadataChangeSet = /* metadata setting */


// upload it
val createFileAtRootResult = Drive.DriveApi
                                  .getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                                  .createFile(
                        mGoogleApiClient, metadataChangeSet, newDriveResult.driveContents)
                                  .await()
```

I want to limit this job `only wifi`

---

I think use this code will make solve this problem, but this is can't be solution directly.

```
val isWifiConnection =
    (context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager)
                       .activeNetworkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
```

because when I upload using above code, transfer buffer will filled and drive forces file to upload whenever while connected internet.

And I can't find relevant function for limit to wifi.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I know there is a setting in the Google Drive app that restricts the app to WIFI only. Is this setting used?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/TransferPreferences ... I think you can use this

Comment: @Dagmar It was solved before, but your answer is pretty good.